# Reserve dynamic memory with the new operator

Tags: c++

I'm learning new operator and I have the next question: 
I want to reserve new memory when I add a new subject and if I do this way I lose all the previus content of array. 
So, how can I do this if i have to reserve memory each time that i want to add a new subject? Or in other words, how i reserve memory without lose the previus?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Subject {
public:
    Subject() { m_name = "";
                m_hours = 0;
    }
    string getName() { return m_name; }
    int getHours() { return m_hours; }
    void setName(string name) { m_name = name; }
    void setHours(int hours) { m_hours = hours; }
private:
    string m_name;
    int m_hours;
};

class Person {
private:
    string m_name;
    int m_age;
    Subject *m_subjects;
    int m_nSubjects;
public:
    Person() {
        m_name = "";
        m_age = 0;
        m_nSubjects = 0;
    }
    ~Person() {

    }
    string getName() { return m_name; }
    int getAge() { return m_age; }
    void setName(string name) {
        m_name = name;
    }
    void setAge(int age) {
        m_age = age;
    }
    void addSubject(string name, int hour);
    void showSubjects();
};

void Person::addSubject(string name, int hours) {
    m_subjects = new Subject[m_nSubjects+1]; *the problem is here, all the previus content is lost*


    m_subjects[m_nSubjects].setName(name);
    m_subjects[m_nSubjects].setHours(hours);
    m_nSubjects++;
}

void Person::showSubjects() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_nSubjects; i++) {
        cout << m_subjects[i].getName();
        cout << "\n";
        cout << m_subjects[i].getHours();
    }
}


int main() {
    int nSubjects;
    string name;
    int hours;

    Person person1;
    person1.setName("Name 1");
    person1.setAge(30);

    cout << "Subjects to add: ";
    cin >> nSubjects;
    for (int i = 0; i < nSubjects; i++) {
        cout << "Name of subject: " << "\n" << endl;
        cin >> name; 
        cout << "Hours: " << "\n" << endl;
        cin >> hours;
        person1.addSubject(name, hours);
    }

    person1.showSubjects();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can understand me.

Comment: You would want `Subjects` in `Person` to be a container. Have you been exposed to the standard library? Know about `std::vector`?

Comment: `std::vector<Subject>` will solve literally *all* your problems. This is the part where you tell us the neanderthal instructor says you aren't allowed to do that, followed by all sane engineers that actually code for a living thumping their heads on their desks.

Comment: @lakeweb yes, but I want to do this without external functions because I' m learning

Comment: I had to stop thumping my head. Broke too many desks.

Comment: Remy is addressing that. It is an over complicated way to do it. In modern C++, `new` and `delete` should never come into play. You would the likes of `std::make_shared_ptr`. That is what you should be learning.

Comment: @Chariot you are doing a right thing. This is the base, the rest is just sugar. See Ramy's reply and continue lerning.

Comment: The instructor may just be setting the stage to introduce `vector`. There's nothing quite like going through the machinations of dealing with heap allocation/deallocation to appreciate `vector` and other containers in the standard library. At least if it doesn't first scare students away from C++.

Comment: Thinking about it. Yes, understanding there is a heap and that `new` and `delete` are fundamental, is important for C++. I spoke too quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *copy* the existing data to the new array before you then replace the previous array (which you are leaking, BTW), eg:

```
void Person::addSubject(string name, int hours) {
    Subject *new_subjects = new Subject[m_nSubjects+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < m_nSubjects; ++i) {
        new_subjects[i] = m_subjects[i];
    }

    new_subjects[m_nSubjects].setName(name);
    new_subjects[m_nSubjects].setHours(hours);

    delete[] m_subjects;
    m_subjects = new_subjects;
    m_nSubjects++;
}
```

You also need to free the current array in your `Person` destructor to avoid leaking as well:

```
~Person() {
    delete[] m_subjects;
}
```

And you also need to add a *copy constructor* and a *copy assignment operator* to `Person` as well, to avoid future problems with multiple `Person` objects sharing the same array in memory if you assign one `Person` to another:

```
Person(const Person &src) {
    m_name = src.m_name;
    m_age = src.m_age;
    m_nSubjects = src.m_nSubjects;
    m_subjects = new Subject[m_nSubjects];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_nSubjects; ++i) {
        m_subjects[i] = src.m_subjects[i];
    }
}

Person& operator=(const Person &rhs) {
    if (&rhs != this) {
        Person copy(rhs);
        std::swap(m_name, copy.m_name);
        std::swap(m_age, copy.m_age);
        std::swap(m_nSubjects, copy.m_nSubjects);
        std::swap(m_subjects, copy.m_subjects);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

And, if you are using C++11 or later, you should (optionally) also add a *move constructor* and *move assignment operator* to `Person`, too:

```
Person(Person &&src) {
    m_name = std::move(src.m_name);
    m_age = src.m_age; src.m_age = 0;
    m_nSubjects = src.m_nSubjects; src.m_nSubjects = 0;
    m_subjects = src.m_subjects; src.m_subjects = nullptr;
}

Person& operator=(Person &&rhs) {
    Person movedTo(std::move(rhs));
    std::swap(m_name, movedTo.m_name);
    std::swap(m_age, movedTo.m_age);
    std::swap(m_nSubjects, movedTo.m_nSubjects);
    std::swap(m_subjects, movedTo.m_subjects);
    return *this;
}
```

See the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for more details.

A better solution is to use `std::vector` instead, let the compiler handle all of these details for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

class Subject {
public:
    Subject() {
        m_name = "";
        m_hours = 0;
    }

    Subject(std::string name, int hours) {
        m_name = name;
        m_hours = hours;
    }

    std::string getName() const { return m_name; }
    int getHours() const { return m_hours; }
    void setName(std::string name) { m_name = name; }
    void setHours(int hours) { m_hours = hours; }

private:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_hours;
};

class Person {
private:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_age;
    std::vector<Subject> m_subjects;

public:
    Person() {
        m_name = "";
        m_age = 0;
    }

    std::string getName() const { return m_name; }
    int getAge() const { return m_age; }
    void setName(std::string name) { m_name = name; }
    void setAge(int age) { m_age = age; }
    void addSubject(std::string name, int hour);
    void showSubjects() const;
};

void Person::addSubject(string name, int hours) {
    m_subjects.push_back(Subject(name, hours));
}

void Person::showSubjects() const {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_nSubjects.size(); ++i) {
        cout << m_subjects[i].getName();
        cout << "\n";
        cout << m_subjects[i].getHours();
    }
}

int main() {
    int nSubjects;
    std::string name;
    int hours;

    Person person1;
    person1.setName("Name 1");
    person1.setAge(30);

    std::cout << "Subjects to add: ";
    std::cin >> nSubjects;
    for (int i = 0; i < nSubjects; i++) {
        std::cout << "Name of subject: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, name); 
        std::cout << "Hours: ;
        std::cin >> hours;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        person1.addSubject(name, hours);
    }

    person1.showSubjects();

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```